# Acer Revo RL80 graphics unsupported?

Tags: intel-graphics, acer, intel-hd

I have just purchased an Acer Revo RL80 net top computer. I've been trying to get Ubuntu up and running on it with quite  a bit of trouble. The only way I can get it to boot is through using the "nomodeset" parameter.
Unfortunately this results in very poor performance, especially in video playback.

Trying to boot without this set just gets me either a completely black screen that goes nowhere, or an endless cycle of bright flashing colours and static.

Is there any way of using Ubuntu with the working Intel HD drivers?

This is the computer: [Acer Revo L80 Nettop PC](http://www.ebuyer.com/395476-acer-revo-l80-nettop-pc-dt-smcek-002)

Answer (score 0):

Try Modifing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=i915:modeset=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1      i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 pcie_aspm=force"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After running `update-grub` restart Ubuntu!

NOTE: You may wish to also try with `i915.modeset=0`
Also it maybe worth trying the following:

edit the file `/etc/mkinicpio.conf` and add:

```
MODULES="intel_agp drm i915"
```

I hope it helps!